# Format SQL output where value is either 0, 1, or 2

Tags: sql

I am using database schema with the following column

```
TRAFFIC_DIRECTION 
tinyint 
The direction of traffic. Enum ( unknown = 0; inbound = 1; outbound = 2)
```

When I run query, TRAFFIC_DIRECTION displays as

```
TRAFFIC_DIRECTION
1
2
2
1
1
1
2
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
```

How do I make it such that, instead of outputting 1 it outputs "inbound", and instead of 2, it outputs "outbound"

Comment: Future note - On SQL questions, please specify the type of database you are using.  MSSQL varies from Oracle and so on, people answering need to know what you are using to get their answer right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some RDBMSs support an ENUM type, but all of them support a `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT id,
    CASE TRAFFIC_DIRECTION
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Unknown'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Inbound'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Outbound'
        ELSE 'ERROR'
    END
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select case
         when traffic_direction = 1 then 'inbound'
         when traffic_direction = 2 then 'outbound'
         else 'unknown'
       end as direction
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN TRAFFIC_DIRECTION = 0 THEN "UNKNOWN"
     WHEN TRAFFIC_DIRECTION = 1 THEN "inbound"
     WHEN TRAFFIC_DIRECTION = 2 THEN "outbound"
     END AS Traffic_Word
FROM sometable
WHERE some criteria
```